# Why cannot I transform the string "Feb 13 23:30:01 2014" to Date in R?

Tags: r, string, date, static

I am trying to convert strings like "Feb 13 23:28:34 2014" to Dates. But the "as.Date" function only produced "NA"s. How can I do it correctly?

```
head(time)
[1] "Feb 13 23:28:34 2014" "Feb 13 23:30:01 2014" "Feb 13 23:32:01 2014"
[4] "Feb 13 23:35:48 2014" "Feb 13 23:43:45 2014" "Feb 14 00:07:05 2014"
time <- as.Date(time, format = "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
head(time)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the NA. `str <- "Feb 13 23:28:34 2014"; as.Date(str, format='%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
#[1] "2014-02-13"`

Comment: @akrun me too, example works well, I do not understand why the NAs.

Comment: What is your locale? Is "Feb" the correct abbreviation for "February"  in your language? You might need to change to an English locale.

Comment: You can try typing `date()` to see what system your locale is using.

Comment: Check `class(time)` before to convert it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roland suggested, it's likely a locale issue. Try what's in the *Example* section of `?strptime`.

```
R> lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")  # store current time locale
R> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")    # Use the "C" time locale
[1] "C"
R> x <- c("Feb 13 23:28:34 2014","Feb 13 23:30:01 2014","Feb 13 23:32:01 2014",
+        "Feb 13 23:35:48 2014","Feb 13 23:43:45 2014","Feb 14 00:07:05 2014")
R> # If you want a Date object (no time)
R> (d <- as.Date(x, format = "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))
[1] "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13"
[6] "2014-02-14"
R> # If you want a POSIXt (date/time) object
R> (p <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))
[1] "2014-02-13 23:28:34 CST" "2014-02-13 23:30:01 CST"
[3] "2014-02-13 23:32:01 CST" "2014-02-13 23:35:48 CST"
[5] "2014-02-13 23:43:45 CST" "2014-02-14 00:07:05 CST"
R> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)  # restore original time locale
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I am a Chinese R leaner. It is a locale issue.

Answer (score 0):

The time is not in standard format. This should do the trick. It is ugly code, I admit.

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

time  <- c("Feb 13 23:28:34 2014","Feb 13 23:30:01 2014","Feb 13 23:32:01 2014","Feb 13 23:35:48 2014","Feb 13 23:43:45 2014","Feb 14 00:07:05 2014")
year <- substr(time,start = 17,stop = 20)
time <- gsub(pattern = substr(time,start = 16,stop = 20),replacement = "",x = time)
time <- paste(year,time,sep = " ")

time  <- ymd_hms(time)

time

[1] "2014-02-13 23:28:34 UTC" "2014-02-13 23:30:01 UTC"
[3] "2014-02-13 23:32:01 UTC" "2014-02-13 23:35:48 UTC"
[5] "2014-02-13 23:43:45 UTC" "2014-02-14 00:07:05 UTC"
 time <- as.Date(time, format = "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
 time
[1] "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-13"
[6] "2014-02-14"
```

If your intention is to convert into time format this is the trick. If you want to convert into some other time format, that will also work.

Comment: There is no need to do all that. Their code would work fine if their locale is correct.

Comment: He is losing information in converting time. "2014-02-13" and etc, is not the output he is looking for, he clearly wants to convert into time data type. That i have done.

Comment: How do you know that's not what they're looking for? They said they wanted Date and they're getting `NA`. Replacing the `as.Date` call with `as.POSIXct` would be far simpler.

Comment: You think the above is simple? really? anyway, it is opinion.